# How to solve the error of cannot estimate gas in local network

Tags: blockchain, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am getting the below error while deploying a contract locally using hardhat.

Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="Transaction reverted: trying to deploy a contract whose code is too large"

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit on how big your contracts can be; please read [this article](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/downsizing-contracts-to-fight-the-contract-size-limit/#why-is-there-a-limit)

Actually I bumped in to the same stone a while ago and found out that i could deploy "library contracts" to fight oversized monolitic contracts.. please read [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/130551/deploy-contract-that-uses-a-library-with-public-functions) as it might give you some insight on how to tackle this

Answer (score 0):

Add allowUnlimitedContractSize: true to your hardhat.config.ts under defaultNetworks.networks both "hardhat" and "localhost".

Comment: this will only work locally, it means that if you make a contract that exceeds the limit, you will not be able to deploy it to mainnet